# Cannot delete Amazon S3 key that contains bad character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just began to use S3 recently. I accidentally made a key that contains a bad character, and now I can't list the contents of that folder, nor delete that bad key. (I've since added checks to make sure I don't do this again).

I was using an old "S3" python module from 2008 originally. Now I've switched to boto-2.0, and I still cannot delete it. I did quite a bit of research online, and it seems the problem is I have an invalid XML character, so it seems a problem at the lowest level, and no API has helped so far.

I finally contacted Amazon, and they said to use "s3-curl.pl" from http://aws.amazon.com/code/128. I downloaded it, and here's my key:

```
<Key>info/&#x1b;[01</Key>
```

I think I was doing a quick bash for loop over some files at the time, and I have "lscolors" set up, and so this happened.

I tried
    `./s3curl.pl --id <myID> --key <myKEY> -- -X DELETE https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/info/&#x1b;[01`

(and also tried putting the URL in single/double quotes, and also tried to escape the '[').

Without quotes on the URL, it hangs. With quotes, I get "curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 50". I edited the s3-curl.pl to do `curl --globoff` and still get this error.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What happens if you try accessing it from the AWS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/ ?

Comment: The AWS console interface says "an error occurred" if I try to view the folder, or try to delete the folder.

Answer (score 5):

This solved the issue, just delete the main folder:

```
aws s3 rm "s3://BUCKET_NAME/folder/folder" --recursive
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the s3cmd tool from [here](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).  You first need to run

```
s3cmd fixbucket <bucket name that contains bad file>.
```

You can then delete the file using

```
s3cmd del <bucket>/<file>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case there were newlines in the key (however that happened..). I was able to fix it with the aws cli like this:

```
aws cli rm "s3://my_bucket/Icon"$'\r'
```

I also had versioning enabled, so I also needed to do this, for all the versions (versions ids are visible in the UI when enabling the version view):

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key "Icon"$'\r' --version-id <version_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in this situation recently, to list the items you can use:

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my_bucket --encoding-type url`

the bad keys will come back url encoded like:

`"Key": "%01%C3%B4%C2%B3%C3%8Bu%C2%A5%27%40yr%3E%60%0EQ%14%C3%A5.gif"`

spaces became `+` and I had to change those to `%20` and `*` wasn't encoded I had to replace those with `%2A` before I was able to delete them.

To actually delete them, I wasn't able to use the aws cli because it would urlencode the already urlencoded key resulting in a 404, so to get around that I manually hit the rest API with the DELETE verb.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this case. I had newline at the end of my bucket. The following command solved the matter.

```
 aws s3 rm "bucket_name"$'\r' --recursive
```